# How to implement CPU & memory docker container restrictions on GCE + MYSQL backup/restore?

Tags: mysql, docker, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run docker containers on Google Compute Engine. I am running into a resource management issue. I wanted to run two containers on the GCE instances.

1. Nginx+PHP-fpm.
2. Mysql

The issue is that i need to run cpu and memory restrictions. The grub setting (swap accounting) does not seem to work. Is there any workarounds.

Secondly, can anyone advise if its possible to use **google/mysql** container to do mysql backup and restore ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Best Regards
Hareem Haque

Comment: Have you solved your issues? Your fist question is difficult to understand. Could you elaborate: "The grub setting (swap accounting) does not seem to work".  About your second question, it should be totally doable with mysqldump command. I see no reason why it wouldn't

Comment: @MarCialR Thanks for the response. Yes my issue has been resolved. The following is a link to #Docker swap accounting.

Link: https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#memory-and-swap-accounting


Secondly, the **google/mysql** container does not do auto restore. I did manage to get some containers for backups and restores.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did manage to solve my problem. I just started using GCE **"Container-VM"** image for all my container deployments.

The second part of my problem was to automate backups and restores. I did not get exactly what i wanted. However, I did manage to get some semi-automated containers to do my backups & restores for me. The **Google/Mysql** container does not indeed to auto restores.

Best Regards
Hareem Ul Haque

Comment: @Robert - its interesting others classify these things as VM's too. I don't consider them full VMs. That's why I refer to them as *"lightweight VM"*.